# The region of convergence of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{3^n}}(z^2-z)^{3^n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I was asked to find the region of convergence of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{3^n}}(z^2-z)^{3^n}$. I guess it is $1$ and my thought is that I first write it as
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_mz^m,
\end{equation*} where $a_m=0$ for $3^n<m<3^{n+1}$. Then it is a gap series and I hope to find a subsequence $\{a_{m_k}\}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[m_k]{a_{m_k}}=1,
\end{equation} but I failed. Please give me some hints.

Comment: What power series?

Comment: The series converges if $|z||z-1| <2$ and diverges if $|z||z-1| >2$.

Comment: @ Angina Seng, I have deleted the word "power" in the question.

Comment: @ Gae. S., Thanks for your comment. I will change the title to the correct wording.

Comment: @KKWong The issue is not with the word "power", but with the word "radius".

Comment: It also diverges when $|z(z-1)|=2$.